# sqlite query with intersect and except

Tags: sqlite

here is a sqlite query that I have to perform but i want to perform except operation first and then intersection. By default, intersection is given more precedence over except. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

```
select a, b from table1 intersect select a,b from table2 except  select a, b from table3
```

I tried putting the queries in brackets, but it threw me an error "`[ near "(": syntax error ]`".

```
select a, b from table1 intersect (select a,b from table2 except  select a, b from table3)
```

Comment: try this: (SELECT a, b FROM table1) INTERSECT ((SELECT a, b FROM table2) EXCEPT (SELECT a, b FROM table3));

Comment: @iKishore 
no that doesn't work either. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Compound queries do not support parentheses, but subqueries do:

```
SELECT a, b FROM table1
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a, b FROM table2
               EXCEPT
               SELECT a, b FROM table3)
```

Please note that `INTERSECT` does *not* have higher precedence than `EXCEPT`, the [actual rules](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) are:

> When three or more simple SELECTs are connected into a compound SELECT, they group from left to right.

Since `INTERSECT` is commutative, you could simply write this particular query as:

```
SELECT a, b FROM table2
EXCEPT
SELECT a, b FROM table3
INTERSECT
SELECT a, b FROM table1
```